# Where can I get wallpaper of Stackoverflow and Stackexchange?

Tags: support, stackoverflow

Do *stackoverflow* and *stackexchange* provide their **wallpaper**? I enjoy the style of stackoverflow site, but couldn't find the wallpaper.

Comment: What exactly is it you would like to have?

Comment: erm... what?? o.O

Comment: wallpaper with stackoverflow theme.

Comment: The simple answer is "there is none" but I'm sure if you asked on the meta site, some kind soul with artistic talent could whip something up...

Answer (score 3):

There is no official repository of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange Approved™ wallpapers, but this question has been asked on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39049/where-can-i-get-stack-overflow-wallpapers), where you might find some questionable candidates.